# Can I have anonymous, password-protected file sharing links?

Tags: onedrive-for-business, team-sites, microsoft-teams

We have configured the SharePoint settings for our M365 tenant so that 'Anyone' sharing is disabled for both SharePoint and OneDrive. We are almost always perfectly happy to limit sharing to people in the organization or explicitly invited guests, and we like that this is the global default setting.

However, there is exactly *one* specific use case made impossible by this configuration: the situation where we sometimes need to make a big file (too big to mail) available to people outside the company.

Is it possible in M365/SharePoint to create DropBox/NextCloud-like anonymous URLs, preferably password-protected and time-limited, while keeping the global "don't allow anonymous sharing" default intact?

The only alternatives I can think of are either to always register people we want to mail something to as a Guest User of a special-purpose Team (but that is a lot of admin hassle, and the guests then have to log in to M365 just to get a file), or else to relax the global sharing restriction, and then make sure everything else but a 'sharing' site is explicitly closed off -- but that seems very error-prone. As I said, in 99% of the cases the strict default suits us very well.

Does anyone have any ideas if it is possible to achieve what I want? Am I missing something?